# UWP toast without vibrate?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have an UWP app that does a background download and I have toast notifications on the progress, however I don't want it to annoy the user every time with sounds and vibration.  I found the ToastAudio and set that with silent, now no sounds for progress updates which is great until I have a device with vibration.  Now my phone was vibrating about every 2 seconds for the 3 minutes it took to download.

I've not been able to find a vibration option in the toast specs, is there one?  For now I've limited my updates to every minute and when done to minimize the annoyance.

Comment: It sounds like you are using toast notifications for something they weren't meant for. Toast notifications should inform users about actionable events, not continuous updates of a single operation. Besides, isn't that going to bombard the action center with new, transient entries?

Comment: The status uses a single group key so each replaces the previous, so never more than 1 entry is in there.  Clicking it takes you to the pending downloads screen in my app, but it provides a notification about progress and completion because you may be waiting to leave a network until it finishes (downloads are from intranet sources).  I see it much like email or text notifications where it shows you the message and you can tap or dismiss, and a tap takes you to a specific screen in the app where you can execute more actions.  If I get lots of emails I get the same bombardment you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew from the Windows Notifications team here.

You should use a "ghost toast" for your scenario - the toast will silently go into Action Center without vibrating or alerting the user. To create a "ghost toast", set the `ToastNotification.SuppressPopup` property to true.

That way, the user can stay informed about your download by checking Action Center without the notification popping up, or making a sound, or vibrating. You don't even need to set your audio to silent - it will be muted if `SuppressPopup` is true.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, vibration on toast notifications is built-in behavior controlled by user. You can't override it, but you can offer user to change settings for your app thru the [ms-settings:notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) protocol. Just in case - there are not options to open notification settings for specific app.

Comment: I had heard the same for wanting silent toast notifications, thankfully I stumbled on that one but now that I've seen how that works if vibration was there I would expect it in the same spot, oh well.  Thanks.